# Can i attach an object to an email with nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, jspdf, nodemailer

I need to send a email with nodemailer, but in the email i need to attach an pdf that i generate using jspdf, the thing is that i cannot attach an object to an email, i can attach a file getting it's path, a string, and a lot of other things, but an object i cannot.

I tought of saving the pdf and using it's path, but this is all working on an VM, so i dont want to use too much cpu power or ram space.

I also tried using JSON.stringify() in the pdf, but it didn't work, and the file attached to the email was empty.

Comment: Yes you can. Check this link https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach your pdf file by using `content` property of `attachments` object. It support many formats - string, path to file, buffer, fs read stream, etc.
See this [docs](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/).

In case with jspdf you can use [output()](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output) method

```
const message = {
    // ...
    attachments: [
       {
           filename: "mypdf.pdf",
           content: pdfObject.output('arraybuffer')
       }
    ]
};
```